# Elementor Form : show a section after a submit and based on user selection

Tags: jquery, forms, show-hide, elementor, sections

I would like to display a different section according to the users' answers to our form and after the submission.

I used elementor for my wordpress website.

I tried this :

`

```
<script>
jQuery(".elementor-field-group-industry").show();
jQuery("#form-field-industry").change(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).val() === 'Carvin') && jQuery("#terminer").click(function(){
        jQuery("#sect1").show();
    }
    else {
        jQuery("#sect1").hide();
    }
});


</script>
```

Comment: First of all, you have not closed your if condition properly. Secondly, when you want to bind the click event? When you change jQuery("#form-field-industry")? Please provide some more information.

Comment: Or as per my understanding you want to trigger a click event when jQuery("#form-field-industry") changes.

Comment: I change it for jQuery("#sect1").hide();
jQuery("#terminer").click(function(){
    if(jQuery("#form-field-industry").val() === 'Immobilier' && jQuery("#form-field-app-1").is(':checked'))
        jQuery("#sect1").show();
    else
        jQuery("#sect1").hide();
});